# Check if there is specific object in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, object, ifnull

In my data class I have

```
public final data class Customer(
    val customerId: String,
    val customerName: String,
    val email: List<Email>?
)

public final data class Email(
    val emailId: String,
    val emailAddress: Set<String?>? = null
)
```

My function

```
fun process(incomingCustomer: Customer) {
  //I want to check if incomingCustomer has the email object in it and I have something like
   if(customer.email?.isNullOrEmpty() == true){
     prin("no Email found")
   }
}
```

I was curious if there is a better way to check if the `incomingCustomer` has the `email` object

Comment: btw, you don't need the `final` keyword here. Kotlin classes cannot be inherited by default (they need an explicit keyword `open` or `abstract` for this purpose), and *data classes* cannot be inherited at all

Comment: Yes, the better way is to disallow null, and replace it with empty, so you don't have to handle the null case.

Answer (score 0):

`fun <T> Collection<T>?.isNullOrEmpty()` is an extension function on a *nullable* type, so you should call it without `?.`.

`email?.isNullOrEmpty()` won't be invoked at all if `email` is `null` (thus, `email?.isNullOrEmpty() == true` is false as `email?.isNullOrEmpty()` is also `null`)

So, `if (customer.email.isNullOrEmpty())` works good in your case